# Pug not passing one specific argument into mixin block

Tags: html, pug

Running into quite into a weird issue where one specific argument doesn't get passed into the block part of a mixin.

### Input Pug

```
mixin a_ref(ref)
    if ref 
        a(ref=ref)
            block 
    else 
        block

span=name+source+aspect_ratio
br
+a_ref(ref)
    span=name+source+aspect_ratio
```

### Expected HTML

```html
<span>2018 project/images/unsplash1.jpegaspect-[1/1]</span>
<br>
<a ref="xxx">
    <span>2018 project/images/unsplash1.jpegaspect-[1/1]</span>
```

### Actual HTML

```html
<span>2018 project/images/unsplash1.jpegaspect-[1/1]</span>
<br>
<a ref="xxx">
    <span>undefined/images/unsplash1.jpegaspect-[1/1]</span>
```

I've tried renaming the "name" attribute into something else but the issue persists. Any help is welcome!

EDIT: Another thing to add: the attributes are defined as they are passed into another mixin from the actual html template

````
mixin pf_img({name, source, ref, width="1/2", aspect_ratio="1/1", description, is_video=false} = {})
  span=name+source+aspect_ratio
  br
  +a_ref(ref)
    span=name+source+aspect_ratio

+pf_img({name:"2018 project", source:"/images/unsplash1.jpeg", ref:"xxx", description:"2018"})```
````

Answer (score 0):

FIXED:

For anyone who runs into this issue, I narrowed it down to something further down in the mixin, where I redefined the "name" attribute; apparently that makes it undefined further up when putting it into a block.